# Number to text - error results with fraction

Tags: math-mode, enumitem, fmtcount

When I use integer with following code, it works correctly. But fraction (say 4.7) is used, errors result.

```
\documentclass{minimal} \usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\numberstringnum{4}

\numberstringnum{4.7}

\end{document}
```

How can I rectify the problem

Comment: The `fmtcount` package seems geared towards LaTeX counters which, by definition, are integers.

Comment: How do you want the printed result in the case of decimal numbers?

Comment: @egreg I use it to convert currency. Rs 8.7 is Rupee eight paisa seventy (preferred) or eight point seven rupee

Answer (score 2):

You have to split the number at the period and use `\numberstringnum` on the two parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\spellamount}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{.}}m}{%
  \dospellamount#1%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dospellamount}{mm}{%
  \numberstringnum{#1}
  \IfValueT{#2}{%
    \spellcomma\ 
    \expandafter\numberstringnum\expandafter{%
      \number\numexpr\ifnum#2<10 10*\fi #2\relax
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\spellcomma}{comma}% modify to suit

\begin{document}

\spellamount{8}

\spellamount{8.7}

\spellamount{8.75}

\end{document}
```

[image]